# C++ code with OpenGL on OSX using CGL/NSOpenGL without XCode?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, opengl, gcc

I want to use CGL or NSOpenGL to create an OpenGL window without using XCode (compile with command line gcc).  I am developing something that is cross platform, and I'd like to keep the code divergence to a minimum if I can!  My codebase is fully C++ at the moment.  Is this at all possible?  I am new to OSX and I haven't touched objective C.  I looked through the developer docs and grabbed some example files.  They are all using xcode.  I successfully compiled the source and linked with the right framework, but the whole app bundle, xib, and info.plist thing seems a bit over the top.

Comment: Should definitely be possible. Is it a full screen app?

Comment: So you got it to work as a plain binary, and you just need to pack it into an App bundle? Why not make that App bundle once, with Xcode, and then have your build script replace just the binary (and maybe update the version number)?

Comment: @KrisVanBael I compiled the code found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GLFullScreen/Introduction/Intro.html but It complains about xibs and other stuff.  I suppose I could use xcode just to create the bundle, but it seems kind of hackish

Comment: @KrisVanBael I will do as you said and Build the app bundle once and replace the binary.  Do you know how I can tie in my c++ code with the obj-c stuff?  Cheers for the response!

Comment: Mixing c++ and obj C is possible. Use file extension .mm if you mix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [fltk](http://fltk.org/) and [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) should have enough AGL/CGL code. I've built and run cmdline GL apps on OS X with fltk-1.3.0. It uses the AGL sub-system however, which is deprecated. SDL uses CGL and NSOpenGL for its Quartz video layer: `./src/video/quartz`

Use the obj-c flags for the compiler, if you need to build a `src.m`, and let the native g++, llvm-g++, clang++, or whatever, take care of the linking. You might need to add `-framework CGL -framework OpenGL` as well as `ApplicationServices` and `Cocoa`. A lot of the answer depends on what you mean by 'code divergence'.

Comment: I will look in to the SDL code.  I am trying to stay away from Carbon!  I haven't had any trouble linking the libraries.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

This is bare-bones as one can get:

```
// g++ glInfo.cpp -o glInfo.x -framework OpenGL 

#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    CGLContextObj     ctx; 
    CGLPixelFormatObj pix; 
    GLint             npix; 
    CGLPixelFormatAttribute attribs[] = { 
        (CGLPixelFormatAttribute) 0
    }; 

    CGLChoosePixelFormat( attribs, &pix, &npix ); 
    CGLCreateContext( pix, NULL, &ctx ); 
    CGLSetCurrentContext( ctx ); 

    printf("Vendor:   %s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR)                  ); 
    printf("Renderer: %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER)                ); 
    printf("Version:  %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION)                 ); 
    printf("GLSL:     %s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)); 

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The thing is, the OP wants to create an "OpenGL window". The public interface to CGL does not expose this functionality. You would either have to use AGL (deprecated) or NSOpenGL (Objective C) to accomplish this.

Comment: Actually, in El Capitan you can create an "OpenGL window" using CGLSetFullScreenOnDisplay().  You don't need AGL or NSOpenGLView.  The only downside is CGL only gives you fullscreen windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can build apps without using Xcode, but if you want users who aren't sys admins to use them, you'll need an app bundle (and hence .plist) and (unless it's a game) a user interface beyond what OpenGL offers. You don't need to create a .xib for your UI. You can do it all programmatically, though using .xibs is far easier for most things. Why don't you want to use the tools designed to help you? I'm not saying they're the best, but they beat using only a command-line interface. (Once you have an Xcode project for your app, though, you can build it from the command-line and even automate building it.)

Comment: I didn't know that I could automate building the app from the command line once I have the xcode project!  Where can I find out more about that?  There is no UI besides what is inside opengl.  I just don't want to update code, then have to go into xcode to build each time.  Thats my biggest gripe.  Can you give me a clue about how I can get my c++ code to play nicely with the obj-c stuff?  cheers for the response!

Comment: @mightcouldb1: This isn't a forum. You asked a question, and you got your answer. You're now asking another question, about mixing Objective C with C++. This is best done with the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: I agree with Nicol Bolas that you should ask another question about this. But to help you know what to ask, you can look for info on `xcodebuild`. BTW, if my answer helped you, please check the green checkbox on the left!

Comment: @NicolBolas In the future I will ask these questions elsewhere.  Sorry about that.  Your OpengGL tutorials have been very helpful to me, thank you for putting them together.

Comment: @user1118321 Thanks for the info!  I will check out xcodebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it "by hand" (I used to do it at NeXTStep times), but it is a pain before it works for the first time.
XCode uses makefiles under the hood. You can find and adopt the makefiles in

```
  /Developer/Makefiles
```

(pre XCode 4.3)
or for XCode 4.3 in

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Makefiles
```

Good luck!

Comment: I am looking through the /Developer/Makefiles/pb_makefiles and it looks like what I'm looking for!  I wasn't able to locate the second path.  My Xcode.app file is inside of /Developer/.  I am using OSX Lion.  Either way, I will continue to look through these makefiles.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For the build system, I recommend CMake/CPack which will help you to keep it cross-platform and to build app bundles. For NSGL, it's possible using Obj-C++, but I don't have any code at hand.

Comment: I have never used CMake but I will have a look at it!  Thanks for the reply!